# How to translate this piece of C# generics to Java

Tags: java, c#, generics

Given the following C# code, how can I translate this to Java?

```cs
public class Stop : IComparable<Stop>
{
    public int CompareTo(Stop other) { ... }
}

public class Sequence<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { ... }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { ... }
}

public class Line<T> : Sequence<T>, IComparable<Line<T>>
    where T : Stop
{
    public int CompareTo(Line<T> other) { ... }
}
```

I have difficulties translating the definition of class Line to Java. My first attempt would be the following:

```
public class Line<T extends Stop> extends Sequence<T> implements Comparable<Line<T>> { ... }
```

However, the compiler reports the following error for `extends Sequence<T>`:

```
Error: type argument T is not within bounds of type-variable T
```

Changing the definition to

```
public class Line<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Sequence<T> implements Comparable<Line<T>> { ... }
```

fixes the error, but does not accurately reflect the intent: I want to enforce that all type arguments used with Line must be a sub-type of Stop. Using `T extends Comparable<T>` would allow arbitrary types that implement the interface.

I do not understand the reason for the error. Is there some way to express this relationship without changing the structure of the types or is this a limitation of Java's generics?

Edit: Visit https://www.onlinegdb.com/S1u9wclnH to see a stripped down version of my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your definition of `class Sequence`.

```
public class Sequence<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : IComparable<T> { ... }
```

This C# class makes use of the fact that `IComparable` is contra-variant, so the C# class doesn't require exactly `T: IComparable<T>`, but is also happy if `T` is comparable with one of its base classes. Thus the code works even if `T` is instantiated with a class derived from `Stop`.

Java does not have declaration-site variance, but use-site variance (wildcards). Your Java `Sequence` class cannot be instantiated for classes derived from `Stop`, but your `Line` class might be. Thus the compiler error.

To fix this, you need to translate C#'s declaration-site variance to Java's wildcards whenever you use `Comparable` in bounds:

```java
class Sequence<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Iterable<T> { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this and providing an easy solution. It's easy to get fooled by co-/contra-variance. I had thought about trying wildcards, but I do not understand them completely, so it would have taken me way longer to get it right...